# `if` condition to check that all values are not `null` does not seem to help TS narrow values within the `if` block

Tags: typescript

I have a function `doSomething` that needs an argument of `Type1 | Type2`.

There are 2 possible values `a` and `b` I can pass into this function, and both cannot be `null` at the same time. However, the values can be individually `null`.

After checking that at least one value from `a` or `b` is not `null`,

1. I proceed to call `doSomething(a)` if `a !== null` or
2. `doSomething(b)` in other cases (as `b` cannot be `null` if `a` is `null`)

However, TS cannot seem to detect that `b` cannot be null, and shows me a warning

```
Argument of type 'Type2 | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type1 | Type2'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Type1 | Type2'
```

**Is there a way to resolve the warning without using annotations or another check on the value of `b`? I'm trying to understand why the narrowing of types to exclude `null` fails within the `if` block.**

Simplified Code below:

```
type Type1 = {
    key: 'one'
    height: number
}

type Type2 = {
    key: 'two',
    weight: number
}

const DoSomething = (args: Type1 | Type2) => {
    if (args.key === 'one') return `Height: ${args.height}`;
    return `Weight: ${args.weight}`
}

let a: Type1 | null = Math.random() > 0.5 ? null : {key: 'one', height: 10};
let b: Type2 | null = Math.random() > 0.5 ? null : {key: 'two', weight: 5};

if (a !== null || b !== null) {
    if (a) {
        DoSomething(a)
    } else {
        DoSomething(b) 
// TS warning: Argument of type 'Type2 | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type1 | Type2'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Type1 | Type2'
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just add `} else if(b) {`. What's wrong with adding a one more check...

Comment: @DecPK I was trying to avoid a redundant conditional check.

Answer (score 1):

Let's focus on this code block copied from you:

```ts
if (a !== null || b !== null) {
    if (a) {
        DoSomething(a)
    } else {
        DoSomething(b)
    }
}
```

While the logic works, it requires a lot more thinking process than necessary. How about you simplify it to this equivalent code block?

```ts
if(a !== null) {
    DoSomething(a)
}
else if(b !== null) {
    DoSomething(b)
}
```

As a side-effect, the TS warning will be gone. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use a type assertion in DoSomething like this :

```
DoSomething(b as Type1 | Type2);
```

By using the type assertion b as Type1 | Type2, you're essentially telling TypeScript that you are confident that b is not null at this point, and it should be treated as either Type1 or Type2.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid assertions if possible.